# Find the area included between the curves $x^2 +y^2 =a^2$ and $\sqrt{|x|} +\sqrt{|y|} =\sqrt{a}$ ($a>0$) and find its area.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> Find the area included between the curves $x^2 +y^2 =a^2$ and $\sqrt{|x|} +\sqrt{|y|} =\sqrt{a}$ ($a>0$) .

Comment: at first you must make a plot of your curves

Comment: I have done it , my answer was (pi -(2/3))*a^2.Wanna see different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's
$$4\int\limits_{0}^a\left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2\right)dx=$$
$$=4\cdot\frac{\pi a^2}{4}-4\int\limits_{0}^a\left(a-2\sqrt{ax}+x\right)dx=\left(\pi-\frac{2}{3}\right)a^2.$$